# center items of a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do so:

[image]

all items in center.
Elements should be arranged in the form of an alternation of 4 and then 3 elements

Now it looks like this:

This is a screenshot layout inspector

and on devices
**layout bounds**
[image]
Code:

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 12);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (position % 7) {

                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    return 3;
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:

                    return 4;
            }

            return 3;

        }
    });
```

XML:
item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/circle_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Post the original picture of "show layout bounds" mode one. It should have pink coloring.

Comment: @ azizbekian
update

Comment: I cannot see something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=show+layout+bounds&pws=0&gl=us&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7qfSt3OnSAhXCI8AKHQGrA1EQ_AUICSgC&biw=1032&bih=601)

Comment: @azizbekian  i add layout bounds

Comment: @azizbekian
what wrong in my code?